# Player doesn't jumps in Box2D implementation

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

Well, i'm trying to learn andEngine. I was able to successfully implement the move functionality for the player. Now, i'm trying to make the player jump using Box2D. I referred few online tutorials to do this but i am not able to make the player jump. Here's my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
@Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
            throws Exception {
         scene = new Scene();
        final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - back.getWidth()) / 2;
        final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.back.getHeight()) / 2;

        Sprite backgr = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, back,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
         rcs1 = new Sprite(85, 250, rc1,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
         rcs2 = new Sprite(195, 240, rc2,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
         rcs3 = new Sprite(295, 250, rc3,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());


        ans = new AnimatedSprite(86, 245, ttr,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                this.setPosition(pX, pY);
                super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

            }
        };
        pw = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH),
                false);
        final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(2f,0f, 0.9f);
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, ans, BodyType.DynamicBody,
                PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0));
        bodyr1 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, rcs1, BodyType.StaticBody,
                objectFixtureDef);
        bodyr2 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, rcs2, BodyType.StaticBody,
                objectFixtureDef);
        bodyr3 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, rcs3, BodyType.StaticBody,
                objectFixtureDef);

        pw.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ans, body, true, true));
        scene.attachChild(backgr);
        scene.attachChild(rcs1);
        scene.attachChild(rcs2);
        scene.attachChild(rcs3);
        scene.attachChild(ans);
        pw.setContactListener(this);
        scene.registerUpdateHandler(pw);
        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(scene);

    }
private void jump() {

            body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(body.getLinearVelocity().x, 12)); 
                }
}
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when are you calling the `jump()` method? Make sure it really gets called, maybe by using a log message. Second, instead of

```
body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(body.getLinearVelocity().x, 12));
```

you should do

```
body.setApplyForce(new Vector2(0, 120));
```

Setting a velocity directly is frowned upon and should be done only in a few exceptional cases such as adding a new body to the simulation that has some initial velocity. Otherwise use forces or linear impulses.

Third, what does this code do?

```
    ans = new AnimatedSprite(86, 245, ttr,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            this.setPosition(pX, pY);
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

        }
    };
```

It looks to me that you want your animated sprite to be driven by the physics body (you register the connector) but then you are setting its position to some `pX` and `pY`. The physics body might be jumping, but the Sprite is drawn always at [pX, pY] due to this code.